# How to set the marker color to black in google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I change the color of the marker using this function 
 `mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));`
I can't find HUE_BLACK.
How can I set the marker color to black?
I prefer to avoid custom drawable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such a thing as HUE_BLACK. The Black color has every hue value in possible range (0-359) and every saturation value in possible range (0-100) but specific brightness value (0). [Check this](http://colorizer.org/). That means that you cannot set the black marker color without setting the brightness value to 0, but you can only set the hue value in the BitmapDescriptorFactory...

So what you should do is to use custom drawable that you are trying to avoid :( . More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html).

Also, what I've learned is that the default markers may appear different on different devices depending on what drawables are bundled into Google Play Services, so you should avoid them when possible...

P.S: The problem about setting only hue colors has been reported as an issue and we are still waiting for Google to implement the appropriate functionality...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, so I will move on custom drawables ;)